# Seeing frequent log entries for martian TCP packets (potentially causing performance issues)

Tags: linux, networking, security, ip

I am seeing a nearly constant stream of these entries in its service node logs, not sure what they mean? I have read up on this and some say that it is a security issue and others says it is nothing to worry about. Can anyone give me advice? Virtually there is nothing in the datacenter that uses 192.168.X.X IP. Are the martian IP logs to be of any concern?

````
Feb  8 02:09:10 xyzsvc01 kernel: [14891219.7735391] ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 fe 00 08 00        ..............
Feb  8 02:09:10 xyzsvc01 kernel: [14891219.7735441] IPv4: martian source 192.168.197.128 from 0.0.0.0, on dev eth0
Feb  8 02:09:10 xyzsvc01 kernel: [14891219.7735451] ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 fe 00 08 00        ..............```
````

Comment: How many is a "constant stream"? Here you show 2 headers 6 microseconds apart  which is a lot if it is continuous! For a gigabit ethernet you can get just under 1.5 million minimal size packets per second, and every 6 microseconds is about 10% of this. The is nothing intrinsically wrong with getting packets from rfc1918 addresses but it does hint at device misconfiguration.

Comment: This week we seen over 255K events of martin source IP in one of our hosts. How can I find what device is misconfigured?

Comment: Normal way to find the device is to look at the MAC address associated with the packets. If you have managed switches then use SNMP to examine the forwarding tables to find which port they are from. This is a job for the data center networking team. A quarter of a million events in a week is about 1 every 2 seconds on average. Enough to be annoying but not enough to cause performance issues.

Comment: Thank you I will need to follow up with the networking team.

Answer (score 1):

I see this all of the time, but it has not yet been an issue.
I had this come up where I used to work. It was bugging me for some time until we figured out it was caused by how the network team had subnetted something on our network.

Have also seen local apps calling 0.0.0.0 and this was causing local martian generation. Maybe look at /etc/hosts/ for misconfig.
I would try to figure out what is causing it before you disable it!

Logging Martian hits in /var/log/messages can be disabled by adding 
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
to /etc/sysctl.conf

w/o reboot:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: I don't have that file /etc/systemctl.conf. What exactly am I looking for that could tell me it's misconfigured?

Comment: It might be called /etc/sysctl.conf or you might have /etc/sysctl.d/ as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

They might be misconfiguration somewhere, or an attack attempt by someone who can't (reliably) fake origin addresses. Both merit investigation.